# Data type mismatch in criteria expression error in C# trying to insert data in Microsoft Access using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private OleDbConnection bookConn;
private OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = null;
private String connParam;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        connParam = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Validation.accdb") + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
        bookConn = new OleDbConnection(connParam);
        bookConn.Open();

        oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into tblClients(Firstname,Lastname, Phone, StreetAddress, City, ZipCode) values('" + fName.Text + "','" + lName.Text + "'," + Convert.ToInt64(phone.Text) + ",'" + address.Text + "','"+ city.Text + "', " + Convert.ToInt32(zipcode.Text) + ")", bookConn);
        oleDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        bookConn.Close();
        Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path);
    }
}
```

All I know is the problem is in my `INSERT INTO` command.
`Firstname`,`lastname` ,`streetaddress`,`city` are Strings and `phone` & `zipcode` are integers. I'm not sure how to fix this error :/

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: How would I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to use parameters.

Comment: something like this?

Comment: OleDbCommand add = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblClients (" + "Firstname,Lastname, Phone, StreetAddress," +"City, ZipCode"+ ") VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6)", bookConn);
            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("1", fName.Text);
            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("2", lName.Text);
            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("3", Convert.ToInt64(phone.Text));
            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("4", address.Text);
            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("5", city.Text);
            add.Parameters.AddWithValue("6", Convert.ToInt32(zipcode.Text));
            add.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Regardless of what your actual error may be, PHONE AND ZIP CODE ARE NOT INTEGERS. They are strings of digits.  If you specify zip code as an integer, you will INVARIABLY somewhere neglect to format it as five digits, and someone (me) from NJ or elsewhere in the Northeast will get pissed off at your site.  If you use phone as an integer, you will undoubtely hit an overflow somewhere.